# Are any two $\ell$-adic Tate twists (non-canonically) isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, etale-cohomology

Recall that for a prime $\ell$, the $\ell$-adic Tate twist is defined by $$\mathbb Z_{\ell}(n) := \varprojlim_r \mu_{\ell^r}^{\otimes n}.$$  As abelian groups, we have a (non-canonical) isomorphism $\mu_{\ell^r}^{\otimes n} \simeq Z/\ell^r$.  Does this imply that all the Tate twists $\mathbb Z_{\ell}(n)$ are (non-canonically) isomorphic?

Comment: In the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_l(n)$, the $n$ does not appear. This is strange. Shouldn't it be something like $\varprojlim_r (\mu_{\ell^r})^{\otimes n}$? In any case, the answer to your question is probably no, because projective limits are only functorial for families of morphisms which are compatible with the transition maps (i.e. morphisms of diagrams). This does not disprove that there is any isomorphism, of course, but it shows that we cannot simply write it down.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Sure, you are right. I have edited the question.  I also think that the answer is probably no; but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: However, if the field over which we consider these as constant sheaves has $l^r$-th roots of unity, then multiplication by such a thing should give you such family of maps, I guess.

Comment: They are isomorphic in the sense that they are all of them free $\mathbb{Z}_l$ modules of rank 1. However, they are not isomorphic as Galois representation.